# Switching views creating memory leak

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I have been switching views with navigator.pushView over and over again but it seems to continually take up more memory. Any leads on what it could be?

Am I changing views wrong?

Comment: Can you show us some code ? Maybe it's another part of it that causes memory leaks...

Comment: Sample Code might be useful to analyze

Comment: Make sure that all references to your view are removed and nullified, otherwise they will stay in memory forever.

The most likely culprit here would be event listeners on your view or one of its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DennisJaamann is correct in his comments - couldn't mark it as an answer since there wasn't anything to mark.

Answer (score 0):

If pushView works anything like the Objective-C equivalent, it will save all the views you push into a stack. It's meant to be used as for a hierarchical interface, where you go deeper into the tree and then use popView to move back out.

Comment: In flex, when you push or pop a view, all other views except the default view of your application should be removed by default

Comment: That sounds odd - how would you pop a view to return to a previous view unless all views are stored?

Comment: Because flex doesn't keep a list of references to the view instances themselves, but rather to the views' Classes and creates a new instance every time, hence the experienced memory leak.